# What happen to my flutter app if I restore my mac?

Tags: macos, flutter

I have an app in production in the appstore, but what happen if I remove all my mac, reinstall all Xcode, all android studio ? I'll always be able to upgrade my app ? What I need to save before remove all ? ( Archives ? other file ?)  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need your Apple Developer Profile keys and Certificates from your Keychain as well. That'll include keys for Notifications, Production vs Development keys, etc.